# Sendmail as a client and SSL/TLS support in submit.cf

Tags: ssl, sendmail

I am using Sendmail as a **client** using only submit.cf to send legitimate emails from some linux boxes (sendmail -C submit.cf -f email_address).
The SMTP server of some of my email addresses requires SMTP AUTH over SSL/TLS (Gmail). I managed to work out the SMTP AUTH part, but I can not find a way to enable SSL in submit.cf.

How can I configure sendmail to attempt TLS when submitting mails to google as an authenticated gmail user in this scenario?

Comment: Just a small note, solely because I've been burned by this myself: You need to understand the difference between using SMTP with STARTTLS and using SMTP over an SSL/TLS socket. I believe Google mail uses STARTTLS approach. See [here](http://solarisrants.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/why-starttls/) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK by default sendmail tries to use STARTTLS whenever available for outgoing connections.

**IF** you use smtp.gmail.com:587 as your smart host **THEN** gmail does not accept messages without *SMTP AUTH* **AND** gmail does not offer *SMTP AUTH* before STARTTTLS command.

Relaying via custom port (587) is covered in sendmail FAQ.
*3.39 How do I send using an alternate port?*

Comment: Hey, that works.. I already tried that but apparently i had some firewall problems so I thought this is a no go. Thank you for keeping me pointed in the right direction.